# How can I keep track of changes made in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I do not want to call store.subscribe method. I just want to sync the store state with the component's state.
[I am trying to make a shopping cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPkGw.png)
- There is a component **CartItems** that displays **SignleCartItem** by passing props to SingleCartItem component using map function.

Whenever user updates the quantity SignleCartItem dispatches an action and store saves the total items added to the cart and their price.

Now the problem is that the component that displays SubTotal and Total of the cart items do not sync the state of the store with the its state ( which displays total ).

### Making it simple:

> One component updates the store state, other component is not syncing
>   it on run time.

PS: Please ignore the product detail :P

Comment: I don't know if I understood your problem. Are you saving the same value (total) both in the store and in the CartItems component's state?

Comment: no i am saving the total in redux store and want to sync it with other component that displays the total items n calculate other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show store state 'total' in your component. You need to connect your component to the store.
An example in es6:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{ ... }
const mapStateToProps = state => ({total:state.total});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SomeComponent);
```

doc about redux connect function is here:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: actually i am not using connect container. I am using react komposer for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of changes made in redux store, like you said in your title, you can try [redux-logger](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger). You will be able to see, in your google chrome console, every action created and every changes in your store, like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `store.subscribe()` use [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) to bind Redux with React.

In your root component, import the store you created with `createStore()` and provide it to a component using `Provider`

```
import App from './App.js'
import store from './store/index.js'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux' 

const myApp = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<myApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Then, inside any component you want to listen to the state, use `connect` to connect the parts of state you want in that component by mapping them to the props

```
import {connect} from 'redux-react'

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
            <div>
        )
    }
}
```

Map the state to the props before you export the component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    title: state.title
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```